# Importing data skip lines with fopen

Tags: matlab, fopen

I try to skip lines 5 to the end of the file from a .txt-file I import into Matlab.

```
fidM = fopen('abc.txt', 'r');
for i = 5:150
    fgetl(fidM);
end
buffer = fread(fidM, Inf) ;
fclose(fidM);
fidM = fopen('xyz.txt', 'w');
fwrite(fidM, buffer) ;
fclose(fidM) ;
```

The code above does not do the job somehow. Any ideas?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. `fgetl` doesn't care what the value of `i` is. Are you trying to read lines 151 to the end of the file?

Comment: I said what I wanted in the first line. "Skip the first 5 lines till the end". Sorry if that was not clear enough. I just can skip lines by erasing them. So I want to "keep" my first 5 lines and write them in a new file. Get it?

Comment: So in other words, you just want to read the first 5 lines?

Comment: Exactly. BUT delete the rest though. Or if it is possible just read the 5 lines and save them separately.

Comment: What do you mean "delete the rest"? You're writing out to a different file. At the end of the day, what do you want inside of `abc.txt` and `xyz.txt`

Comment: `abc.txt` stays as told by the permission `r` so I only read from this file. First 5 lines of `abc.txt` have to be written into `xyz.txt`

Comment: Right, so there's no deleting.... you just want to simply write *just the first 5 lines* of `abc.txt` into `xyz.txt`

Comment: Yes! Make sure you write your solution as an answer. I am willing to accept it then if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code currently reads the first 146 lines of your file, discards them, then reads the remainder and writes *that* out to a file. Instead, if you want to just write the first 5 lines of `abc.txt` into `xyz.txt`, then do something like the following:

```
fid = fopen('abc.txt', 'r');
fout = fopen('xyz.txt', 'w');

for k = 1:5
    fprintf(fout, '%s\r\n', fgetl(fid));
end

fclose(fid);
fclose(fout);
```

Or you can remove the loop and do something like this:

```
fid = fopen('abc.txt', 'r');

% Read in the first 5 lines
contents = textscan(fid, '%s', 5);
fclose(fid);

% Write these to a new file
fout = fopen('xyz.txt', 'w');
fprintf(fout, '%s\r\n', contents{1}{:});
fclose(fout);
```

Comment: The problem with your code is that it modifies my textfile somehow and does not give me the output I want. It concatenates the words into a sentence. The textfilt I have consists of five lines with sentences. Any other solution? Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: @MatlabNewb Are you on windows? If so, try opening the file with something other than notepad

Comment: @MatlabNewb Updated it since you're on windows and notepad is awful you'll want `\r\n` instead of `\n` alone

Comment: Your first code snippet did exactly what I wanted :) So simple but very effective! Thank you very much and have a nice weekend!

Comment: P.S: If I want to read line 6-11 how can I achieve that with your code?

Comment: @MatlabNewb well you could call the `textscan` to read in the first 5 lines, ignore those, and call `textscan` again with a `7`  to read in the next 7 lines and then process the rest exactly the same.